# Could someone explain the meaning and structure of this sentence?

Tags: meaning, sentence-structure, syntax

> For it reminds us that *far from being an unavoidable consequence of technological progress*, the nature of work always remains a matter of social choice.

I heard that when "for" is used as a conjunction, it means "because~", but still I don't get how an adjective comes right after that when I thought there should have been a sentence. This makes it difficult for me to understand what the former clause means and how it is structured.

I'd appreciate it if someone could help me understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"For" is indeed a conjunction here roughly meaning "because", and it is followed by a clause (which is I think what you mean by "sentence").

The clause is, "*it reminds us that...the nature of work always remains a matter of social choice*". The structure "*far from being...progress*" is unrelated to the conjunction "for", and could be removed from the sentence without affecting its grammar or overall meaning.